# Android videoview video not play after once play video in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

In `WebView` when I play a **YouTube** video it plays the video successfully but it gives following error message :

```
OnBufferingUpdateListener is null. Failed to send MEDIA_BUFFERING_UPDATE message.
```

Even if I finish this activity the video stops but still the above error continuously occurs.

When I open another activity and tried to play video in videoview control then it gives error message

```
Can't play video. and following error code -

E/MediaPlayer(10207): Error (-38,0)
```

Is there any way to solve these problems?

Comment: [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12418014/android-webview-playing-html5-h-264-mp4-video-how-to-get-at-the-mediaplayer)